# Getting AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 with no other stack trace

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

When using Retrofit and Coroutines to fetch data from an API I sometimes get an app crash with no stacktrace in Logcat except this: `AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1`

Comment: Please provide enough information so the users can figure out what the problem is. e.g your stacktrace or your api service class

Comment: @saman that's the problem, that line I posted is the only error, no other stacktrace. That's why I posted this self-answered question, it's hard to Google for

Answer (score 55):

This is usually caused by Retrofit throwing a common exception like UnknownHostException (if there's no Internet) and coroutines swallowing the exception if you didn't specify a CoroutineExceptionHandler.

So add a coroutine exception handler in your launch code, something like this:

```
val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler{_, throwable ->
    throwable.printStackTrace()
}

fun getFromApi() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO + coroutineExceptionHandler) {
        retrofitService.getStuffFromInternet()
    }
}
```

Note this just logs the error to Logcat so you can see the missing stacktrace. You still need to figure out what's causing it.

Comment: you are a legend. Getting extra debugging info saved my life

Comment: If we are using Coroutine, compulsory to use `coroutineExceptionHandler `?

Comment: really you have good knowledge of android debugging. You helped me a lot and saved my time.

Comment: If we are using Coroutine, compulsory to use coroutineExceptionHandler ???

Comment: This resolve my issue. Please check as correct answer

Comment: it actually solved my problem , i thought I got extra debugging but it solved also , thanks

Comment: I am testing my code without internet and this solved my issue thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this type of error many times and what worked for me was to uninstall the app from the emulator and then installing it again.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this after me. I got the issue when trying to call `LifecycleResumeEffect` and this was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Default Dispatcher Worker - 1 or Default Dispatcher Worker - 3, I don't know the reason for these errors but I think it is some issue with the emulator device you are using or maybe if you have import some other project and run it on that emulator device, than later on you might see this error.

What you can do to solve this issue :
**Just create a new emulator device or use a physical device.**

Comment: First try uninstalling the app and installing again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the emulator/phone is not in the airplane mode

Answer (score 1):

check if the endpoint is correct. I had this problem and solve by this way